# Pause audio file not play on receiver side in sip in android

Tags: android, kotlin, sip

I'm working on a project where I'm using the SIP (Linphone library). I'm facing an issue where, when the caller dials a call and the receiver accepts it, if a new call comes in on the caller side, the ongoing call gets paused (a pause event occurs in SIP **`onCallStateChanged`**). However, on the receiver side, the pause file is not played. Below, I'm sharing some of my code.

```
 private var callHandler: Core? = null    

fun init(
        context: Context,
        username: String,
        password: String,
        sipDomain: String,
        sipIp: String,
        sipPort: String
    ) {
    

        if (isRegister or isRegisterInProgress) {
      
            return
        }


     
        callHandler = factory.createCore(null, null, context)

        callHandler?.start()
        callHandler?.disableRecordOnMute = true
        callHandler?.playFile = getPauseFile(context)
        callHandler?.useFiles=false
        callHandler?.enableEchoCancellation(true)
        callHandler?.enableEchoLimiter(false)
        register(username, password, sipDomain, sipIp, sipPort)
    }



    private fun getPauseFile(context: Context):String{
        val mPauseFile="${context.filesDir.absolutePath}/play.wav"
        val lFileToCopy = File(mPauseFile)
        if (!lFileToCopy.exists()) {
            val lOutputStream: FileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(lFileToCopy.name, 0)
            val lInputStream: InputStream = context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.play)
            var readByte: Int
            val buff = ByteArray(8048)
            while (lInputStream.read(buff).also { readByte = it } != -1) {
                lOutputStream.write(buff, 0, readByte)
            }
            lOutputStream.flush()
            lOutputStream.close()
            lInputStream.close()
        }
        return mPauseFile
    }




    fun register(
        username: String,
        password: String,
        sipDomain: String,
        sipIp: String,
        sipPort: String
    ) {
        
        callHandler?.let { core ->
            val transportType = Constants.transportType
            val authInfo =
                factory.createAuthInfo(username, null, password, null, null, sipDomain, null)

            val params = core.createAccountParams()
            val identity = Factory.instance().createAddress("sip:$username@$sipDomain")
            params.identityAddress = identity

            val address = Factory.instance().createAddress("sip:$sipIp:$sipPort")
            address?.transport = transportType
            params.serverAddress = address
            if (!params.outboundProxyEnabled) {
                params.outboundProxyEnabled = true
            }
            params.registerEnabled = true
            val account = core.createAccount(params)

            core.addAuthInfo(authInfo)
            core.addAccount(account)

            // Asks the CaptureTextureView to resize to match the captured video's size ratio
            // core.config.setBool("video", "auto_resize_preview_to_keep_ratio", true)

            core.defaultAccount = account
            core.addListener(coreListener)


        } ?: return

    }
```

"I'm call init function from the main activity. Now, could you help me identify what might be wrong with the code provided above?"

How i play file on receiver side when caller gone pause state?